# typescript derived class cannot have the same variable name?

Tags: typescript

Why can't typescript derived class have the same variable name? Even these members are private. Is there an alternative to this, or am I doing something wrong?

```
class ClassTS {
    
    private nom: string = "ClaseTS";
    
    constructor() {
            
    }
}

class ClassTSDer extends ClassTS {
    
    private nom: string = "ClassTS";
    
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I found this while practising with TS.

> Class 'ClassTSDer' incorrectly extends base class 'ClaseTS'. Types
> have separate declarations of a private property 'nom'. ClassTSDer
>
> class ClassTSDer

*you could, use protected*; yes but if I do not want to use protected, would I have to use another name?

Comment: Not "although" but becouse there are private u cant have same names. U want to override private property( child class with same property as in parent class always wants to override this).

Comment: "You could use protected" => i had no pain setting it to public in the parent and child class, and it works :D

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The properties must have different names.

Remember that at runtime, JavaScript class instances are just objects, and objects are just mappings from key to value. The property names are the key, and you can't have two different keys with the same name.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I thought I was doing something wrong. or perhaps there was a reserved word for this, your explanation in short, simple and very useful thanks for your time.

Answer (score 11):

The properties must have different names.

If you'll look at the generated ES5 code you can see that declaring a property on the child class with the same name as a private property as the parent will overwrite the parent one thus breaking encapsulation.

```js
/**
 * ClassTS
 */
var ClassTS = (function () {
    function ClassTS() {
        this.nom = "ClaseTS";
    }
    ClassTS.prototype.someMethod = function () {
        console.log(this.nom);
    };
    return ClassTS;
}());
/**
 * ClassTSDer
 */
var ClassTSDer = (function (_super) {
    __extends(ClassTSDer, _super);
    function ClassTSDer() {
        _super.call(this);
        this.nom = "ClassTS";
    }
    ClassTSDer.prototype.childMethod = function () {
        _super.prototype.someMethod.call(this);
    };
    return ClassTSDer;
}(ClassTS));
```

In this case for any function from the parent called in the child will result in **this.nom** having the value "ClassTS" instead of "ClaseTs" as you'd expect from a private property.

The compiler does not complain about the **protected** properties (even though they generate the same ES5 code) because the expectation of encapsulation is no longer there.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I thought I was doing something wrong. or perhaps there was a reserved word for this, you say ...The compiler does not complain about the protected... i had no idea thanks for your time