# Class 'B' incorrectly extends base class 'A' (two private methods named the same)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting the error

> Class 'B' incorrectly extends base class 'A'.
>   Types have separate declarations of a private property 'method'.

```
abstract class A {
  private method() {}
}

abstract class B extends A {
  private method() {}
}
```

When the method in class `A` is commented out, then the error goes away. What can I do to have two private methods that are named the same?

Comment: Naming them differently would work.

Comment: I thought that this was acceptable. It is valid if the two are public.

Comment: That's the problem using just typescript, convert it into plain JavaScript and you can follow the code along how it ends up the way it does,

Comment: Can you convert `A` into an interface, and move the existing `A.method` into a new abstract class that implements `A`?

Comment: `What can I do to have two private methods that are named the same?` -
 When extending one class from another you cannot have two private methods named the same as explained in this - Possible duplicate of [typescript derived class cannot have the same variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708845/typescript-derived-class-cannot-have-the-same-variable-name)

Comment: @earldouglas That makes me make the method public in the class since typescript doesn't seem to allow private/protected methods in interfaces. `Property 'method' is private in type 'B' but not in type 'A'.`

Answer (score 15):

Since Typescript sits on top of Javscript, and Javascript does not allow inherited classes to have different private implementations for a function (all functions will end up on the `prototype` of the class) it makes sense that Typescript would not allow you to do this.

If this were allowed you would be basically be overriding the private member `method` and since it is marked as private it was probably not intended for public consumption/overriding.

You could override the function if you declared it as public/protected

```
abstract class A {
    protected method() { }
}

abstract class B extends A {
    protected method() { }
}
```

Or if you really want to override a private method, you could do the following, although private methods are marked as private for a reason and it may be best to avoid this:

```
class B extends A {

}
(B.prototype as any)['method'] = function(this: B) {
}
```

Comment: Since all methods are public after getting compiled anyways and TypeScript allows for the same public methods, why wouldn't it support the same private methods? They are just going to be public in the end anyways...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn You can use TypeScript playground to see the JavaScript and why it is not possible http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20private%20method()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20private%20method()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Well typescript does not allow you to do many things that you could do in JS. The reasoning here is that the method being marked as private is an implementation detail of the base class, and you should not even know about it much less override it

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Since the method is private, you might be overriding it without even knowing about it, you can still do it if you really, really want to but at least you won't override private implementation details by mistake ..

Answer (score -1):

It's all very strange, but if you really need to, try this:

```
class Foo {
    private go() {
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this["go"] = this.foo;
    }

    private foo() {

    }
}
```